# Excel: insert rows in multiple tables (not plain cellsheets) simultaneously, sans macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-teams

Hello to SU community,

I have an Excel file with **4 tabs**: *RC, PC, TI, Contacts*. The 2nd and 3rd are locked so as to avoid any accidental modification. Tabs RC and PC **each contain one table**, and the table in PC takes some data from the table in RC.

Since 1- PC has to stay locked and 2- both sheets contain a formatted table, not mere unspecific data, selecting two tabs and using the "Insert" command doesn't work.

**Illustration**
What I'm trying to do: On the *RC* tab, on a a cell immediately following a row I want to add, right-click to "Insert" > "New row in the table".
[image: Inserting new row in table in RC]

The result on the *RC* tab: A new table row is created, complete with conditional formatting.
[image: New row in RC]

**What I want to achieve:**
On the *PC* tab, have a new row automatically inserted in the table between 13 and 14.
[image: PC tab]

Current lock configuration for *PC* tab: While tab is locked, I can readily insert a blank row in the table, but not erase it.
[image: Lock configuration]

**Short context:**
One file is passed around users, each tab is filled by a different person. There will be about 20 of these files, each to be filled by a different RC. We assume the RCs are not cellsheet-savvy at all (doesn't know how to re-sort rows by date, won't think about letting blank rows for future use, doesn't even know what an Excel table is, etc. Hence the lock on the other tabs. We really assume the lowest common denominator here.); he or she may want to insert a row anywhere in the table.

**Temporary solution so far:**

1. Put plenty of blank rows at the end of the table;
2. Provide clear instructions to fill in any additional data there;
3. PC person will re-sort everything by hand should the need arise.

Nevertheless, I expect a large number of error by the different RC, and increased workload on PC. The whole process is error-prone.

**Question**

How do I insert a new table row in RC in a way that the newly inserted row *automatically* creates one in the table in PC, each with its own, particular formatting?

The solution would have to only use regular Excel functions, not macros, and be functional even in antiquated Excel versions and the dumbed-down Excel for the web / inside Teams.

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data along with any formula or method you have tried so far,, will help us to fix the issue!

Comment: Do you mean copy and paste the same table from RC to PC with formatting by using formula?

Comment: @RajeshS Not sure how to do that. I could post the data, but the issue at hand here is the formatting and how the formatting is manipulated. Doesn't readily translate to text. Would screen captures be OK?

Comment: screen capture or a link to the screen capture is ok. | "selecting two tabs and using the "Insert" command doesn't work..." Are you inserting a row or a column?

Comment: I hope it's bit clearer that way.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution would have to only use regular Excel functions, not macros

That is NOT POSSIBLE.

Excel functions can change only VALUE of current cells, they can not affect any other CELLS (neither value of them, neither add /remove cells).

There are no "commands" in Excel which could do level of automation asked in the question.

Comment: In this context, "functions" and "commands" are used interchangeably. As said, I do NOT want to change cell values, only manipulate tables.